# Using JavaFX controller without FXML

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

Is there a possibility to use a controller with a JavaFX GUI without using FXML.

I noticed that the FXML file contains an `fx-controller` attribute to bind the controller but i don't find it an easy way to work with it.

Any ideas about have an MVC arch with JavaFX without using the FXML file or JavaFX Scene Builder ?

Comment: You don't have to use FXML or SceneBuilder. You can simply create the objects yourself and add them to your Scene/Stage yourself. It's entirely open as to how you implement it. I've implemented a Screen Management library where it handles either FXML or manually created screens. It can be done :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your question isn't particularly clear to me: you just create the classes and basically tie everything together with listeners. I don't know if this helps, but here is a simple example that just has a couple of text fields and a label displaying their sum. This is what I regard as "classical MVC": the view observes the model and updates the UI elements if the model changes. It registers handlers with the UI elements and delegates to the controller if events happen: the controller in turn processes the input (if necessary) and updates the model.

Model:

```
package mvcexample;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class AdditionModel {
    private final IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper sum = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

    public AdditionModel() {
        sum.bind(x.add(y));
    }

    public final IntegerProperty xProperty() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public final int getX() {
        return this.xProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setX(final int x) {
        this.xProperty().set(x);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty yProperty() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public final int getY() {
        return this.yProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setY(final int y) {
        this.yProperty().set(y);
    }

    public final javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerProperty sumProperty() {
        return this.sum.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final int getSum() {
        return this.sumProperty().get();
    }



}
```

Controller:

```
package mvcexample;

public class AdditionController {

    private final AdditionModel model ;

    public AdditionController(AdditionModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    public void updateX(String x) {
        model.setX(convertStringToInt(x));
    }

    public void updateY(String y) {
        model.setY(convertStringToInt(y));
    }

    private int convertStringToInt(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
            return 0 ;
        }
        if ("-".equals(s)) {
            return 0 ;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
```

View:

```
package mvcexample;

import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;

public class AdditionView {
    private GridPane view ;
    private TextField xField;
    private TextField yField;
    private Label sumLabel;

    private AdditionController controller ;
    private AdditionModel model ;

    public AdditionView(AdditionController controller, AdditionModel model) {

        this.controller = controller ;
        this.model = model ;

        createAndConfigurePane();

        createAndLayoutControls();

        updateControllerFromListeners();

        observeModelAndUpdateControls();

    }

    public Parent asParent() {
        return view ;
    }

    private void observeModelAndUpdateControls() {
        model.xProperty().addListener((obs, oldX, newX) -> 
                updateIfNeeded(newX, xField));

        model.yProperty().addListener((obs, oldY, newY) -> 
                updateIfNeeded(newY, yField));

        sumLabel.textProperty().bind(model.sumProperty().asString());
    }

    private void updateIfNeeded(Number value, TextField field) {
        String s = value.toString() ;
        if (! field.getText().equals(s)) {
            field.setText(s);
        }
    }

    private void updateControllerFromListeners() {
        xField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> controller.updateX(newText));
        yField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> controller.updateY(newText));
    }

    private void createAndLayoutControls() {
        xField = new TextField();
        configTextFieldForInts(xField);

        yField = new TextField();
        configTextFieldForInts(yField);

        sumLabel = new Label();

        view.addRow(0, new Label("X:"), xField);
        view.addRow(1, new Label("Y:"), yField);
        view.addRow(2, new Label("Sum:"), sumLabel);
    }

    private void createAndConfigurePane() {
        view = new GridPane();

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);

        view.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        view.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        view.setHgap(5);
        view.setVgap(10);
    }

    private void configTextFieldForInts(TextField field) {
        field.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>((Change c) -> {
            if (c.getControlNewText().matches("-?\\d*")) {
                return c ;
            }
            return null ;
        }));
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
package mvcexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MVCExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AdditionModel model = new AdditionModel();
        AdditionController controller = new AdditionController(model);
        AdditionView view = new AdditionView(controller, model);

        Scene scene = new Scene(view.asParent(), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is what i was talking about. Using a "Classical MVC" upon JavaFX without FXML; Thanks that is fair enough

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just extend GridPane in your view class? Why make the getAsParent method instead?

Comment: @hubbabubba Basic API design. If the view extended `GridPane` then client code could assign instances of it to variables typed as `GridPane`, eg `GridPane view = new AdditionView(...);`. That means I could never change to using a different layout. The layout should be an implementation detail of the view class, not something exposed to the public API of the class. The way I have it set up, I only guarantee it’s some kind of `Parent`, so I could later change to using a different layout without affecting any other code.

Comment: Shouldn't the Controller be the one that "knows about" and manages the Model and the View? In this example it's the View that knows about both the Model and Controller.

Comment: @petersaints I think what you’re describing is model-view-presenter (MVP), which is what I’d argue the FXML approach is based on. Perfectly good pattern, but it’s not “classical” MVC.

Comment: @James_D I guess that it could turn into an MVP pattern depending on how things get connected inside the Controller. But most MVC examples I have seen usually have the controller as the "glue" between the Model and the View, with the View only having the option of rendering the Model, subscribing to the Model changes through some kind of Observer pattern and dispatching user generated events to the Controller which is responsible for manipulation the Model which in turn may generate a change in the View.
That said, the whole concept of MVC, MVP and MVVM has some overlap: bit.ly/3VPGmHV

Comment: @petersaints “With the view only having the option of rendering the model, subscribing to the model changes … and dispatching user generated events to the controller which is responsible for manipulation of the model”.  Isn’t that exactly what this does?

Answer (score 4):

I use JavaFX extensively and do not use FXML or scenebuilder.  So I can vouch that it can be done.

Below is the auto generated code made by my IDE to get an JavaFX main class.  This will be the root of your application.  You will then add to it to create your application.

```
public class NewFXMain extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what i'm wondering is how to bind the controller to the view without the FXML because I want it as an MVC 3-tier

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah What view? If you're not using FXML, then there's nothing to bind to. You simply pass your calls from UI components to controller components directly. When you create the components you bind their actions to controller actions in code anyway, so there's nothing to bind to in this instance. You only need that methodology for FXML. You can see the action being bound to a control in Jose's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

For the rest of us... Here is a VERY simple example showing how to create a JavaFX form without the use of any FXML files. This example can be used within an app that is already running, so I've skipped the Main class and all that ... it's just meant to show the simplicity of JavaFX.

In a nutshell, you simply create your scene based on a container such as an AnchorPane, then you create your Stage and assign the Scene to the stage ... add your controls then show the stage

```
package javafx;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleFX {

    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    private TextArea textArea () {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setLayoutX(20);
        textArea.setLayoutY(20);
        textArea.setMaxWidth(450);
        textArea.setMinHeight(380);
        return textArea;
    }

    private TextField textField () {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setLayoutX(20);
        textField.setLayoutY(410);
        textField.setMinWidth(450);
        textField.setMinHeight(25);
        return textField;
    }

    private Button button() {
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        button.setLayoutX(240);
        button.setLayoutY(450);
        return button;
    }


    private void addControls    () {
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(0,textArea());
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(1,textField());
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(2,button());
    }

    public void startForm () {
        anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 500, 500);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        addControls();
        stage.show();
    }
}
```